# Node-webkit desktop app restrictions

Tags: node.js, desktop, node-webkit

I need to create desktop application that will run in full screen. And you should not have possibility to close it using alt-f4 or any other keyboard combination.

Is it possible to do using node-webkit or it has any restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not belive it is possible to block <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd>, though I have not tried myself.

They do have a [kiosk mode](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/The-Kiosk-mode), which sounds like it is what you are looking for, but even in kiosk mode you can exit with <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd>.

> After entering Kiosk mode, node-webkit will become fullscreen, and
>   there will be no ways to quit by clicking mouse.
>
> On Linux and Windows, users can still quit node-webkit by pressing
>   keys like <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd> and <kbd>Control + Alt + Del</kbd>, currently node-webkit does
>   not block those keys be because it would make node-webkit behave like
>   virus and be blocked by AV software.

Quoted from https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/The-Kiosk-mode

Answer (score 0):

Old question but, I have the same situation with an app and and node web-kit, using ubuntu+xmonad I can't close using <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> unless I declare the hotkey under Javascript.

This is the content of my package.json

```
"window": {
  "fullscreen": true,
  "toolbar": false,
  "kiosk": true
}
```